# mysqldump over SSH

Tags: mysql, ssh, mariadb

I need to do a mysqldump directly on a remote server with SSH.
The main reason is that I do not have enough space on server to do it normally then copy it over with SSH.

Somehow I need to pipe the output of mysqldump command to SSH.

Ideally this would be a one line command.

Thanks

Comment: Disk space is cheap right now. Add more HDD into your server.

Comment: not quite one line, but [short python script](https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko/blob/master/demos/demo_sftp.py) could be for the basis of it (assembly required).

Comment: @RonvanderHeijden I can use SSH but cannot save the output of mysqldump locally on the server

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try:

```sh
ssh -t user@server \
    "mysqldump \
        -B database \
        --add-drop-table \
        --ignore-table database.logs" > ~/mydatabase.sql
```

Notice that in this example, you don't need to login into mysql. And you do not need sudo permissions.

I also add the `--add-drop-table` and `--ignore-table` options, since these are pretty common.

You can change `> ~/mydatabase.sql` into `| gzip -9 > ~/mydatabase.sql.gz` to compress the file.

Comment: can you offer the other variant also: I am logged into the mysql server and I want the mysqldump piped out

Comment: I think you "don't need to login into your mysql" only if your user@server has implicit mysql access for the target database.

Comment: @Bogdan, if you need to specify credentials, use `mysqldump -u user -ppassword ...` (notice -p and password not space separated)

Comment: Please **DO NOT** use `-ppassword`! Because now, your password is in your bash history.

Comment: Good point, better to set up password less access for user on the remote server.

Answer (score -1):

You wish to store dumpfile remote system not on the server running mysql.
If you execute the MysqlDump command through ssh, the dump file will eventually remain on the server connected to ssh.
You can consider to connect to mysql to execute mysqldump command  via ssh tunneling.

I am not sure any tools support ssh tunneling on linux but Putty can make ssh tunneling on windows.

https://www.linode.com/docs/databases/mysql/create-an-ssh-tunnel-for-mysql-remote-access/

Comment: What do you mean by "eventually remain"? If the output of `mysqldump` is not dumped to any file on the remote server, there is no file to remain on that server